# How to add data to a TableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a tableView in a view which is a subview to my MainViewController.  When the subview is loaded, I have this in my `viewDidLoad` method to initialize my tableData:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

self.listData = array;
[array release];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

Then I use other methods to add to this data within this view.

When I switch back to my other view, however, then bring up this view again, it initializes the data all over again, erasing my changes.  How can I fix this problem?

EDIT:
**I tried to initialize this array in `MainViewController` by doing this:**

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
HistoryViewController.listData = array;
[array release];
```

But it says `Accessing unknown 'setListData:' class method`.

Comment: Not really worthy of an "answer", but I believe you should have your [super xxxx] call at the top of the method, EXCEPT for dealloc (where it needs to go last).  I don't think this will answer your Q but it's just a style thing I noticed that could have unexpected consequences later if you do it that way.

Comment: I never really knew it would make a difference, thanks for letting me know!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not be initializing your array in view did load

```
// this is clearing out all of your data
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.listData = array;
```

There is not much code, but I would suggest initializing the listData property when you initialize the ViewController.

I might suggest you review this [tutorial here on UITableView](http://icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/), and your code above should be edited

```
HistoryViewController.listData = array;
```

should be

```
self.listData = array;
```

Comment: When I initialize which ViewController?  I tried initializing the array in `MainViewController` by doing the code I edited into my post above, but it gives me an error.

Comment: Can you really use `self` when you're referring to another class?